# Where do I get data on how many people move from country to country globally in a year?

Tags: data-request, economics, demographics, migration

I'm calculating total addressable market for a business that has to do with immigration. I need to know how many people physically relocate to another country with intention to settle there permanently, or alternatively how many people acquire legal immigrant status in a foreign country in a year, something like that.

OECD's website calls this [permanent immigrant inflows](https://data.oecd.org/migration/permanent-immigrant-inflows.htm), for 34 OECD countries they estimate it at about 4M a year, but I need data like this for worldwide. Is there a way to find it?

Comment: Worldbank 2010 and 2013 data: http://www.worldbank.org/en/topic/migrationremittancesdiasporaissues/brief/migration-remittances-data

Comment: @StanislavKralin, this shows how many immigrants already live permanently wherever they live. I want to know how many new ones come each year. See the difference?

Comment: Did you search the site for [all questions tagged 'migration'](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migration)?

Comment: @JanDoggen, yes, all 12 of them.

Comment: There is data here, but the flows are far from exhaustive (main source is OECD, the stock looks better, but it's not what you want): https://migrationdataportal.org/

Answer (score 2):

Bilateral migration data is available from sources such as the [United Nations Population Division unit on International Migration](https://www.un.org/en/development/desa/population/migration/data/estimates2/estimates19.asp), [Migration Policy Institute](https://www.migrationpolicy.org/programs/data-hub/international-migration-statistics), and [Migration Data Portal](https://migrationdataportal.org/).  For example, the 2019 UN dataset for migrant stocks by origin and destination is available as `.xlsx` [here](https://www.un.org/en/development/desa/population/migration/data/estimates2/data/UN_MigrantStockByOriginAndDestination_2019.xlsx).